# What identifies a surface on the Bloch sphere as corresponding to a subspace?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, bloch-sphere

Given a [Hilbert subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space), if you normalize every vector and then plot them all on the [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere) (project them all onto the Bloch sphere), you'll get some surface. Do that for every (closed) subspace and you'll get a family of such surfaces. What can generally be said about the surfaces comprising this family? Conversely, what are the "valid" surfaces on the Bloch sphere such that they correspond to subspaces?

Comment: Do you consider $\mathrm{dim}H=2$ i.e. $H\cong \mathbb C^2$?

Comment: The Bloch sphere parameterises all qubit states. Any non-trivial subspace is thus one-dimensional, and corresponds to a single state. These correspond to single points on the Bloch sphere. It seems that you want to mix up the Hilbert space structure with the space that the Bloch sphere is commonly embedded in (i.e. a real three-dimensional vector space) , but they are completely different structures.

Comment: For a subspace of complex dimension $n$, isomorphic to $\mathbb C^n$, you are constructing [complex projective space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_projective_space) $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$. The Bloch sphere is only the special case with $n=2$.